# Primary Category ID for Venue in /v2/venues

Tags: api, categories, foursquare

With the new version of the Foursquare API - I'm finding it difficult to identify the PRIMARY category ID from a /v2/venue lookup. For eaxmple, in the listing below, there is no way to tie the Bowlling Alley to Arts & Entertainment. My fear is that foursquare will introduce new categories and not tell us to which primary category it is being linked to. Any suggestions for this?

Note: I know that I can tell a pull of the categories from /v2/venue/categories and store the IDs of the primary and do a new lookup. Again - my fear is that foursquare introduces a new category and with the primary - it's hard to do the lookup.

```
[categories] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d1e4931735
                        [name] => Bowling Alley
                        [pluralName] => Bowling Alleys
                        [shortName] => Bowling Alley
                        [icon] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [prefix] => https://foursquare.com/img/categories/arts_entertainment/bowling_
                                [sizes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 32
                                        [1] => 44
                                        [2] => 64
                                        [3] => 88
                                        [4] => 256
                                    )

                                [name] => .png
                            )

                        [primary] => 1
                   )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

For now you'll just have to refresh the categories mapping every once in a while to assure yourself that it's fresh. Agreed that not having the parent category in the category object is annoying -- checking if there's a reason why it's not there already.